# Using Rails commands with a disabled command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line

I'm using a public Windows computer where the command line has been disabled. By using Instant Rails I'm able to create customize and test rails apps to some degree but can't use the Rails commands.

Question:

**How do I use these commands with a disabled command line?**

I've tried using SciTe, Notepad++ but all these just access the same disabled cmd so those won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As EmFi said, NetBeans has both a built-in Rails console and the ability to run migrations and Rake tasks from a menu. So with NetBeans, you'd be able to run migration and Rake tasks without needing a command line at all.

Here's another option...

If you're able to install software on the machine, maybe you could install something like [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/). They provide a command prompt with a Unix-like environment. I've used both. Personally, I think MinGW would give you a smoother, simpler experience with fewer gotchas, but Cygwin is very popular.

Answer (score 2):

Some editors that deal with Rails specifically can do this. Netbeans, RadRails and RubyMine come to mind.

However, if your command line is disabled, you're probably not going to be able to `install them either.

Comment: What about Eclipse? That's one I'm familiar with?

Comment: RadRails is available as a plugin for Eclipse.